# Let $n$ be an integer greater than $1$. In a ring in which $x^n = x$ for all $x$, show that $ab=0$ implies $ba = 0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

> Let $n$ be an integer greater than $1$. In a ring in which $x^n = x$ for all $x$, show that $ab=0$ implies $ba = 0$.

**My attempt:** 
We know that $a, b$ belong to a ring. So, $ab$ will belong to the ring.
So, $(ab)^n = ab$.
But, $a^n = a$ and $b^n = b$.
$(a)^n(b)^n = ab$.
Thus, $(a)^n(b)^n = (ab)^n$ and this ring is commutative.
Given $ab =0$, this implies $ba =0$.

Is this solution correct ?

Comment: I don't think that $a^nb^n = (ab)^n$ is enough to decide that $R$ is commutative. (Btw, under the hypothesis $R$ *is* commutative, but I don't think this is a trivial job.)

Comment: (ab)^n = ab ab ab ab ab .... ab.  
All a and all b can be separated only if ab =ba i guess.
So, (ab)^n = (a)^n(b)^n

Comment: A ring $R$ with the property that, for each $x\in R$, there exists an integer $n_x>1$ (possibly dependent on $x$) with $x^{n_x}=x$ is indeed commutative, but this is a rather deep theorem proved by Jacobson. You're not allowed to use this theorem, for the exercise, otherwise it's completely trivial.

Comment: @egreg Do you have a reference?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro It's surely in Herstein's “Noncommutative rings”, http://links.jstor.org/sici?sici=0002-9890(199308/09)100:7<698:AFCINR>2.0.CO;2-I&origin=MSN

Answer (score 20):

$ba=(ba)^n=\underbrace{(ba)(ba)\cdots(ba)}_{n\text{ times}}=b\underbrace{(ab)\cdots(ab)}_{n-1\text{ times}}a=b(ab)^{n-1}a=b0^{n-1}a=0$.

Comment: I am new at rings. As in groups if a belongs to group G , b belongs to G , then ab belongs to same G. You have too used the same argument in ring ??

Comment: @SubhamKumar Those things are not explicitly mentioned because we assume as *given* that addition and multiplication are maps $R\times R\to R$.